# AS3 - how to set VideoPlayer's metadata?

Tags: actionscript

I've set a custom client for a FLVPlayback's netStream, to attach my own functions (onXMPData, onMetaData) to parse the various info myself. However, i'd still like to pass the meta data back to the VideoPlayer. How do I do this? I tried dispatching a METADATA_RECEIVED event with the metadata object (tried dispatching from the client, the netstream, the video player, the flvplayback..), but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, and decided just to open two netstreams for the f4v. The regular, untampered flvplayback one.. and then another just for reading xmpdata.